# D3.js animation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to animate a generated SVG image of 5 icons by rotating them about a particular position arranged to be pointing in 5 directions about a central point.  I'm having problems, either nothing is displayed or the 5 icons are displayed, but when they rotate I cannot get the old positions to be deleted, so after 72 iterations the whole circle is smeared out.

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
let missile = svgContainer.append('defs').append('g').attr('id','missiles');
missiles.append('g').append('use').attr('href','#missile');
missiles.append('g').append('use').attr('href','#missile').attr('transform', 'rotate(72 24 18)');
missiles.append('g').append('use').attr('href','#missile').attr('transform', 'rotate(144 24 18)');
missiles.append('g').append('use').attr('href','#missile').attr('transform', 'rotate(216 24 18)');
missiles.append('g').append('use').attr('href','#missile').attr('transform', 'rotate(288 24 18)');

let i = -1;
let id= 'id0';
setInterval(() => {
  if (i >= 0) svgContainer.select(`#${id}`).remove();
  i = (i+1) % 72;
  id = 'id' + i.toString();
  svgContainer.append('use').attr('id',`#${id}`).attr('href','#missiles').attr('transform', `rotate(${i} 24 18)`);
}, 100)
```

The first part creates a group of 5 icons, each one after the first is rotated by 72 degrees, which works correctly.

The next part is the place where I am having problems.  If I don't use the timer and just display this line:

svgContainer.append('use').attr('id',`#${id}`).attr('href','#missiles').attr('transform', `rotate(${i} 24 18)`);

It works correctly, and I can also increment i and the next line will also be displayed rotated by 1 degree. By manually adding remove(), I can remove the previous set of icons, but in a timer loop, as shown above, it doesn't work.  Note that I need only go through the loop 72 times.

Whether I use select(`#${id}`).remove() to try to remove a particular id from the DOM or select().remove() or selectAll().remove() seems to make no difference.

If someone can kindly advise me on this, I would most appreciate this.

---

OK, thanks for your reply, and the full JavaScript code is below. It was a bit of a pain formatting it correctly here. The HTML code loads this in the head, and in the body I have just the opening svg tag immediately followed by the closing svg tag, so the contents of the svg tag is generated with the JavaScript code.

This works correctly up to the invocation of the setInterval() function, where in the loop the missile icons are rotated by 1 degree on each iteration, but attempts to delete the icons from the previous loop fail, so instead of getting an animation of the missiles rotating, new images are drawn, and after 72 interactions they are completely smeared out. Alternatively by making some other changes nothing is shown at all.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let svgContainer = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 72 36');

  svgContainer.append('rect')
    .attr('width','72')
    .attr('height','36')
    .attr('fill','#024fa2');

  svgContainer.append('rect')
    .attr('width','72')
    .attr('height','24')
    .attr('y','6')
    .attr('fill','#fff');

  svgContainer.append('rect')
    .attr('width','72')
    .attr('height','22')
    .attr('y','7')
    .attr('fill','#ed1c27');

  svgContainer.append('circle')
    .attr('cx','24')
    .attr('cy','18')
    .attr('r','8')
    .attr('fill','#fff');

  let missile = svgContainer.append('defs').append('g').attr('id','missile').attr('fill','#ed1c27');
  let points = [[0,40], [1,40],  [1,38],  [3,38],  [7,44],  [3,30],  [3,18],  [2,17],  [2,4],  [0,0],
               [-2,4], [-2,17], [-3,18], [-3,30], [-7,44], [-3,38], [-1,38], [-1,40], [0,40]];
  let lineGenerator = d3.line();
  let pathData = lineGenerator(points);
  missile.append('path').attr('d',pathData).attr('transform','translate(24,10) scale(0.15)');

  let missiles = svgContainer.append('defs').append('g').attr('id','missiles');
  missiles.append('g').append('use').attr('href','#missile');
  missiles.append('g').append('use').attr('href','#missile').attr('transform', 'rotate(72 24 18)');
  missiles.append('g').append('use').attr('href','#missile').attr('transform', 'rotate(144 24 18)');
  missiles.append('g').append('use').attr('href','#missile').attr('transform', 'rotate(216 24 18)');
  missiles.append('g').append('use').attr('href','#missile').attr('transform', 'rotate(288 24 18)');

  let i = -1;
  let id = 'id0';
  setInterval(() => {
    if (i >= 0) svgContainer.select(`#${id}`).remove();
    i = (i+1) % 72;
    id = 'id' + i.toString();
    svgContainer.append('use').attr('id',`#${id}`).attr('href','#missiles').attr('transform', `rotate(${i} 24 18)`);
  }, 20)
});
```

If I comment out the beginning and end of the setInterval() function and manually add lines such as:

```
svgContainer.append('use').attr('id',`#${id}`).attr('href','#missiles').attr('transform', `rotate(${i} 24 18)`);
```

increment i and id manually then use the remove() function to delete the previous images, it appears to work correctly, but not in the loop.  Obviously something is not behaving in the way I thought it should.

Comment: Can you provide a full example?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do things by hand that d3 already has features for. No worries, but don't underestimate their feature completeness!

In this case, I didn't append 5 loose missiles, but created a fake array to do it for me, then used their `.transition()` service to make them rotate, and finally used their `transition.on('end'` function to make it repeat itself.

```js
let svgContainer = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('viewBox', '0 0 72 36');

svgContainer.append('rect')
  .attr('width', '72')
  .attr('height', '36')
  .attr('fill', '#024fa2');

svgContainer.append('rect')
  .attr('width', '72')
  .attr('height', '24')
  .attr('y', '6')
  .attr('fill', '#fff');

svgContainer.append('rect')
  .attr('width', '72')
  .attr('height', '22')
  .attr('y', '7')
  .attr('fill', '#ed1c27');

svgContainer.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', '24')
  .attr('cy', '18')
  .attr('r', '8')
  .attr('fill', '#fff');

let missile = svgContainer.append('defs').append('g').attr('id', 'missile').attr('fill', '#ed1c27');
let points = [
  [0, 40],
  [1, 40],
  [1, 38],
  [3, 38],
  [7, 44],
  [3, 30],
  [3, 18],
  [2, 17],
  [2, 4],
  [0, 0],
  [-2, 4],
  [-2, 17],
  [-3, 18],
  [-3, 30],
  [-7, 44],
  [-3, 38],
  [-1, 38],
  [-1, 40],
  [0, 40]
];
let lineGenerator = d3.line();
let pathData = lineGenerator(points);
missile.append('path').attr('d', pathData).attr('transform', 'translate(24,10) scale(0.15)');

let missiles = svgContainer.append('defs').append('g').attr('id', 'missiles');

let missileElements = svgContainer.selectAll('.missile')
  .data([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('missile', true)
  .append('use')
  .attr('href', '#missile');

const animate = () => {
  missileElements
    .attr('transform', (_, i) => `rotate(${i * 72} 24 18)`)
    .transition()
    .duration(1440)
    .attr('transform', (_, i) => `rotate(${(i + 1) * 72} 24 18)`)
    .on('end', animate)
}

animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks, and in the mean time before I saw your reply I found another solution. Rather than grouping the 5 missiles into one image, I treated them separately in the loop as follows:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  ....
  missile.append('path').attr('d',pathData).attr('transform','translate(24,10) scale(0.15)');

  let j = -1;
  setInterval(() => {
    j = (j+1) % 72;
    svgContainer.selectAll('use').remove();
    for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
      svgContainer.append('use').attr('href','#missile').attr('transform',  rotate(${i*72+j} 24 18)`);
    }
  }, 20)
});
```

where code between document.addEventListener at the top and missile.append inclusive is unchanged. This now works, but is perhaps less efficient than your solution, which makes use of the SVG built-in animation. I must try this out - many thanks.